# Depth-First-Search: order important?

Tags: python, search, graph, depth-first-search

I have built a Depth-First-Search script with Python which is traversing a graph. Since I have no optimal sorting algorithm the visualization of the DFS looks a bit strange. I mean the order in which my DFS takes the nodes is reproducible but it looks strange because internally my graph class reads a text file line by line and stores the edges (a tuple of nodes) in a set.

When I start my algorithm it expands the starting node, looks for it's neighbors, moves and continues this but because the edges are tuples in a set sometimes the first neighbor which my DFS takes is the bottom node. Next time maybe the right one, and so on. This kind of breaks the visualization since a human would say *ok, if I expand my node, collect the neighbors and deepen/move to the right, I will always deepen the graph to the right*, implying some concrete order.

**My question is: is the solution still correct?** Or should a DFS in this case e.g. walk a straight line to right? The edges in the graph would have to be ordered, then...

I wanted to implement the graph like it is defined in mathematics. That's why I took a set for the nodes and set of tuples (V x V) for the edges.

The actions for each state are: *up*, *down*, *left*, *right*. As long as no wall / obstacle is present.

**Example**:

```
x: wall | s: start | g: goal | o: path taken by the DFS

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x                       x
x                       x
x  s               goo  x
x  oo                o  x
x   o    ooooo     ooo  x
x   oo  oo   oooo  o    x
x    oooo       oooo    x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: note: each time you run `python3 -c 'print(set("abcde"))'` it may produce a different output. See [`PYTHONHASHSEED` envvar](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED)

Comment: Yep. Ironically most times it is the same order but like the example it is never a straight line...my only question is if a DFS is considered correct if it always goes deeper before exploring other neighboring nodes or if it has to additionally do this in a concrete order, so that it would always "walk a straight line".

Comment: there is definitely no "straight-line requirement" for DFS. A similar randomized algorithm is even used to generate mazes, see [the animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Applications)